# Run a script when any of the ancestors contain a particular id, using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to run a script if any of the parents of the element contains a id="someid".

What I tried (if li's any of the ancestors contain id mobile-cat-nav-bar do something)

```
$("li").click(function(e){
                if($(this).parents("#mobile-cat-nav-bar")){
                //do something
                }
});
```

But it doesn't work, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a selector to filter your search. This one is for any ancestor

```
 $("#mobile-cat-nav-bar li").click(function(e){
                    //do something
    });
```

And this one is only for direct parents:

```
$("#mobile-cat-nav-bar>li").click(function(e){
                    //do something
});
```

Comment: #mobile-cat-nav-bar should be immediate parent? or it can be any ancestor of li?

Comment: parents means any ancestor but within a given div ;)